# Get multiple character positions in array?

Tags: javascript

I want to get position of dots and commas in an array.

w.wer,ads,

should give something like:

```
[0] > 1
[1] > 5
[2] > 9
```

How can this be done with javascript?

Comment: Your example isn't clear, do you want the comma and dot index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function getPositions(regex, str) {
    var counts = [], m;
    while (m = regex.exec(str)) {
        counts.push(regex.lastIndex - m[0].length);
    }
    return counts;
}

// Usage:
getPositions(/[,.]/g, 'w.wer,ads,'); // => [1,5,9]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
var getAllIndexesOf = function(str, toFind) {
  var all = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (toFind.indexOf(str[i]) >= 0) {
      all.push(i);
    }
  }
  return all;
}

var result = getAllIndexsOf("w.wer,ads,", [".", ","]);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

Simply loop through each character in the string:

```
var myString = "w.wer,ads,";
var matchedIndexes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
    if (myString[i] == "," || myString[i] == ".") {
        matchedIndexes.push(i);
    }
}
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/JLZRa/).

**Option 2**

If you wanted to get a bit fancier with it, you could create an object that stores the position **and** the character at that position:

```
var myString = "w.wer,ads,";
var matchedIndexes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
    if (myString[i] == "," || myString[i] == ".") {
        matchedIndexes.push(new myMatch(myString[i], i));
    }
}

function myMatch(position, character) {
    this.position = position;
    this.character = character;
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Fancy Result]
    ​

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/RLUTb/).

Answer (score 1):

```
function dotsAndCommas(s) {
  var rv = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
    if (s[i] === '.' || s[i] === ',') rv.push(i);
  }
  return rv;
}
```

Basically, just do it.  There's no shortcut way I can think of to do it with a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not ideal, but as a thought experiment, here is a way to do it with built-in javascript functions (no explicit loops):

```
var pos = mystr.split(/[,.]/).slice(0,-1).map(function(val, i, a) { return a.slice(0, i+1).join('').length+i; });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/hHSB2/

To get rid of the nested `.slice()` which is `O(n^2)`:

```
var pos = mystr.split(/[,.]/).slice(0,-1).map(function(val, i, a) { return a[i] = val.length+(a[i-1]||-1)+1; });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/hHSB2/1/

And, yes, it is still ugly and pointless.

Comment: `map` is not built-in for all browsers :-P

Comment: @kirilloid: I know... which is why this is more of a thought experiment.  You could always make this more awesome-er by putting in the map function a la: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility

Comment: Body of map function may be reduced to `return a[i] = val.length+(a[i-1]||-1)+1;`

Comment: Done! Are we improving bad code?  Or making bad code more unreadable?

Answer (score 1):

Yet another *almost* one-liner:

```
var q = [];
[].forEach.call('w.wer,ads,', function(v, i) { /[,.]/.test(v) ? q.push(i) : 0 } );
// q == [1,5,9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through the string and check each character like so:

```
    var s = "w.wer,ads,";

    var arr = new Array();

    for( var i = 0; i < s.length; i++ ) {

    if( s.charAt(i) == "." || s.charAt(i) == "," )
        arr.push(i);
    }

    for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        document.write( arr[i] );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there're 5 solutions already, I'll write my almost one-liner.

```
function dotsAndCommasPositions(str) {
    var i = -1;
    return str.split(/[.,]/).slice(0, -1).map(function(s){ return i += s.length + 1; });
};
```

Comment: Lol, I had a very similar idea.

Comment: You solution is true one-liner, but `a.slice(0, i+1).join('')` leads to O(N<sup>2</sup>) exec time.

Comment: Yep, not to mention it's very ugly.  :)

Comment: OK, added another one-liner to my answer that should be `O(n)`...  Why am I doing this?? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that loops through all the characters and saves the index of `.` and `,`.

```
​function getPositionsOfDotsCommas(str) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] === '.' || str[i] === ',') {
            result.push(i);
        }        
    }

    return result;
}​
```